# Scraping linked pages while still scraping original page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am scraping a page using requests and bs4. I am trying to scrape links in the page but it still scrapes only the page I am originally on.

Specifically, I am scraping the page at `https://untappd.com/v/beer-culture/893427` to get the beer names from that page. The menu section has a dropdown that links to different menus which also have the same page  structure. I have been able to extract the links to the linked menu pages. See: `print(menu_urls)` in script. I have tried to iterate through the list of links creating a new `soup` for each and scraping it, but it only scrapes the original page n times where n is the length of the list of urls. So in my case, instead of scraping this list:

`['https://untappd.com/v/beer-culture/893427?menu_id=1489', 'https://untappd.com/v/beer-culture/893427?menu_id=116472']`

it only scrapes the original
`https://untappd.com/v/beer-culture/893427`
twice.

Here is my script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

venue_url = 'https://untappd.com/v/beer-culture/893427'
count = 0

response = requests.get(venue_url, headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

def get_menu_beers(soup):
    global count
    menu = soup.find('div', {'class': 'menu-area'})
    beers_all = menu.find_all('ul', {'class': 'menu-section-list'})
    for beer_group in beers_all:
        beers = beer_group.find_all('li')
        for beer in beers:
            details = beer.find('div', {'class': 'beer-details'})
            name_ = details.find("a",{"class":"track-click"}).text
            count = count + 1
            print(count, ' ', name_)

select_options = soup.find_all('select', {'class':'menu-selector'})
options_list = select_options[0].find_all('option')
menu_ids =[]
for option in options_list:
    menu_ids.append(int(option['value']))

menu_urls = []
for menu_id in menu_ids:
    menu_url = str(venue_url)+ '?menu_id=' + str(menu_id)
    menu_urls.append(menu_url)

print(menu_urls)

for url in menu_urls:
    res = requests.get(venue_url, headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    s = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    get_menu_beers(s)
```

Comment: This is trivial. You are not going to progress by asking such questions. It is time to learn how to use breakpoints in your favourite IDE and to debug the code by examining values of the variables at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

In your last few lines of code, you should pass the `url` from the menus instead of `venue_url`:

```
for url in menu_urls:
    #### pass in url not venue_url ####
    res = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    s = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    get_menu_beers(s)
```